# Delete Trigger getdate() returns year 1906

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to set a date/time stamp on deleted records but I'm getting strange results. When this trigger fires it sets the date to 1906!

I've tried using the `GETDATE()` function in the query with an `UPDATE` also on the table properties with a default value. It works fine for records I input manually into the `DELETED_RECORDS` table but any record that's moved in caused by an actual deletion has a 1906 date. I'm not sure what's going on

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Backup_TT_Deleted_Records]
ON [dbo].[tblLLS_TT]
FOR DELETE
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.tblLLS_TT_DELETED_RECORDS
      SELECT *
      FROM   Deleted

      UPDATE dbo.tblLLS_TT_DELETED_RECORDS
      SET    Deleted_DTTM = GETDATE()
      WHERE  dbo.tblLLS_TT_DELETED_RECORDS.Deleted_DTTM IS NULL
  END
```

Also with the above trigger if I enter a record on the `DELETED_RECORDS` table leaving the `Delete_DTTM` null then delete a record causing the trigger to fire it will fill in that record correctly, but the record(s) deleted coming into the `DELETED_RECORDS` table will again have a date of 1906. I also noted the date increments one day per each record.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Any other test you want me to perform let me know and I'll post the results. This one is strange. Thanks!

Comment: What datatype is the Deleted_DTTM column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your insert statement is as follows

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblLLS_TT_DELETED_RECORDS
SELECT *
FROM   Deleted
```

You are neither using an explicit column list for the `INSERT` nor in the `SELECT`.

You say

> I also noted the date increments one day per each record.

My guess is that the columns in the source aren't being inserted into the columns in the destination that you think they are.

It you are deleting a batch of rows with an `IDENTITY` column value between `2191 - 2555` and inserting that `int` value into a `datetime` column you will get an implicit cast to a date in 1906 (the integer is treated as representing number of days since 1<sup>st</sup> Jan 1900)

I'm assuming that the source column is likely `IDENTITY` as that would explain the ascending nature of the dates. To resolve this try specifying both column lists explicitly. Also it is important to note that the equivalent source and destination columns must be in the same ordinal positions. SQL Server won't match them up on the basis of column name so for example.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblLLS_TT_DELETED_RECORDS
            (col1,
             col2,
             col3)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM   Deleted
```

Also you don't need the separate `UPDATE` statement either you can just do this in the `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblLLS_TT_DELETED_RECORDS
            (col1,
             col2,
             col3,
             Deleted_DTTM)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       getdate()
FROM   Deleted
```

Comment: This makes sense, I will give it a shot and let you know. Thank you Martin!

Comment: OK, finished setting up the changes and that was it. Looks like the autonumber ID field was being cast to date/time just as you stated which makes sense given it was incrementing days by 1 each time. Thanks for the help Martin!

Answer (score 1):

If you execute, what value do you get?

```
SELECT GETDATE();
```

Perhaps is misconfigured server time. You could also make the default value of the column "Deleted_DTTM" takes its default system date, then you can skip the last update statement.

Comment: thought the same thing, but the server date is fine. If I insert a record leaving the date time field blank and the trigger fires with the update on null to getdate() it fills in the correct date.